# How to parse this part of XML

Tags: c#, xml

I am very new to XML and have a question regarding parsing of this type of file:

## XML Document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ISBNdb server_time="2005-07-29T02:41:22">
    <BookList total_results="1" page_size="10" page_number="1" shown_results="1">
        <BookData book_id="law_and_disorder" isbn="0210406240">
            <Title>Law and disorder</Title>
            <TitleLong>Law and disorder: law enforcement in television network news</TitleLong>
            <AuthorsText>V. M. Mishra</AuthorsText>
            <PublisherText publisher_id="asia_pub_house">New York: Asia Pub. House, c1979.</PublisherText>
            <Details    dewey_decimal="302.2/3"
                        dewey_decimal_normalized="302.23"
                        lcc_number="PN4888"
                        language="eng"
                        physical_description_text="x, 127 p. ; 22 cm."
                        edition_info=""
                        change_time="2004-10-19T23:52:56"
                        price_time="2005-07-29T02:06:41" />
        </BookData>
    </BookList>
</ISBNdb>
```

How would I go about getting the ISBN number      `<BookData book_id="law_and_disorder" isbn="0210406240">` from this part of the file? Below is the C# that I am using to parse:

## C# Parsing Code

```
 XmlNodeList nodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/ISBNdb/BookList");
            List<Book> books = new List<Book>();

            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                Book book = new Book();

                book.author = node.SelectSingleNode("BookData/AuthorsText").InnerText;
                book.title = node.SelectSingleNode("BookData/Title").InnerText;
                book.ISBN = node.SelectSingleNode("BookData").LastChild.ToString();

                books.Add(book);

                addInfo(book.author, book.title, book.ISBN);
            }
```

I understand that there are different 'nodes' such as 'Title' and 'Details'. However, I do not understand how to get information from within the node 'tags' themselves. Any clarification is greatly apprecated and feel free to correct me on my incorrect 'definitions'

Thanks!

Comment: `I am very new to XML` Better start to learn Linq2Xml, nice API, easier to use.

Comment: If I were to use this Linq2XML, would I be able to easily modify my code to use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
book.ISBN = node.SelectSingleNode("BookData").Attributes["isbn"].Value;
```

isbn is an Attribute of `BookData` and a not Child (ie `Title`)

Answer (score 2):

As suggested, LINQ to XML is a far nicer API. You can either parse or load the XML using `XDocument.Parse` or `XDocument.Load`, then you can create your books:

```
var books = from bookData in doc.Descendants("BookData")
            select new Book
            {
                author = (string)bookData.Element("AuthorsText"),
                title = (string)bookData.Element("Title"),
                isbn = (string)bookData.Attribue("isbn")
            };
```

Comment: Thanks for the help with the LINQ to XML.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var detailsNode = node.SelectSingleNode("BookData/Details");
var dewey = detailsNode.Attributes["dewey_decimal"].Value
```

Note you should use a null guard to ensure the attribute exists before trying to assign its value.

Comment: Thanks for the null check suggestion :)

Answer (score -2):

That's an attribute, in the XML parlance. http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/ might be handy to have a look at, if anything for the "data model" section that breaks down all the various bits. Knowing it's an attribute then makes finding the necessary C# thing easy...